# No me cargan las imagenes [JAVAFX]

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, javafx, eclipse-oxygen

Le he estado dando bastantes vueltas pero no encuentro el fallo, quiero meter imagenes dentro de un 
gridpane usando un arraylist, las imagenes estan dentro del proyecto en la carpeta bin pero no se por que cuando lo pongo en el main al iniciarlo me tira error pero cuando lo comento todo funciona perfectamente.

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Png extends GridPane {
    ArrayList<ImageView> baraja = new ArrayList<>();
    Image png1 = new Image("png1.png");
    Image png2 = new Image("png2.png");
    Image png3 = new Image("png3.png");
    Image png4 = new Image("png4.png");
    ImageView carta1 = new ImageView(png1);
    ImageView carta2 = new ImageView(png2);
    ImageView carta3 = new ImageView(png3);
    ImageView carta4 = new ImageView(png4);
    ImageView carta5 = new ImageView(png1);
    ImageView carta6 = new ImageView(png2);
    ImageView carta7 = new ImageView(png3);
    ImageView carta8 = new ImageView(png4);
    public Png() {  
        baraja.add(carta1);
        baraja.add(carta2);
        baraja.add(carta3);
        baraja.add(carta4);
        baraja.add(carta5);
        baraja.add(carta6);
        baraja.add(carta7);
        baraja.add(carta8);
        Collections.shuffle(baraja);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
            for(int f = 0; f < 2;f++) {
                this.add(baraja.get(i),i,f);
                }
            }
        }
    public ArrayList<ImageView> mazo (){
        return baraja;
        }
    }
```

EDIT : **SOLUCION** : fue una tontería como que en "this.add(baraja.get(i),i,f);" no se puede usar dos veces la misma variable de esta forma, simplemente usé otra variable y funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el método `getResourceAsStream( )` para obtener la imagen que esta junto con tu código.

```java
Image png1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("png1.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un / antes del nombre de la ruta

```
Image png1 = new 
Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/png1.png"));
```